# Removing only a certain value in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to graph data in a column titled "position". 
This column contains the following data:  "Left", "Right", "Center", and, "--".   Unfortunately, the data I am pulling automatically enters "--" when none of the 3 apply. 
I am able to remove the "--" when the column only has 1 value, but cannot figure out an expression to change the "--" to null while keeping the values of "Left", "Right", or "Center" unchanged. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share sample dataset to help understand this requirement better.

Comment: Side note since you said it's using --- spotfire uses this as NULL / Empty for cross tables.

Answer (score 2):

Add calculated column and use `Substitute(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)`

```
Substitute([Column],"--","")
```

[Spotfire Reference](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.2/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm)

```
Replaces all occurrences of Arg2 in Arg1 with Arg3. 
The search is case sensitive.

Example:
Substitute("Test","t","ting") 
Returns:
"Testing"
```